# How to pass an array of strings to Date function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date

I need to get Day's name from a date. For that, I wrote a function(getDayName) using the date method.

I want to pass the date from a JSON to date method. But I'm getting undefined as a result. What I observed was passing an array of two strings. What I need to do is pass one string at a time to a date method. Here's my code. Can some one help me out?

```
//get day name from date

const array = [{
    name: 'Dwayne Langer',
    birthdate: '06-03-2001'
},
{
    name: 'Doffer Henry',
    birthdate: '06-01-2005'
}]

const getBirthDate = array.map(function (birth) {
    return birth.birthdate; 
});
console.log("BirthDate", getBirthDate) 
// BirthDate (2) ['06-03-2001', '06-01-2005']

const dayIndex = new Date(getBirthDate).getDay();
const getDayName = (dayIndex) =>{
    const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    return days[dayIndex];
}
const dayName = getDayName(dayIndex)
console.log("Day Name",dayName);
// Day Name undefined
```

Comment: `console.log((new Date()).toLocaleDateString({}, { weekday: 'long' }));` --> this should get the week-day (like Sunday, Monday, etc) directly from the date. In case you are able to use but had not known it before.

Comment: You are already using map to run code for each array element. Now combine that concept with processing a date string. (also, there's no JSON anywhere in your code. what you have there is an array literal)

Comment: `getBirthDate`, may be better to rename as: `getBirthDatesArray` as it gives an array. Then, instead of `dayIndex` you may use `dayIndices` which would be `getBirthDatesArray.map(d => (new Date(d)).getDay());`. And then, you would get `dayNames = dayIndices.map(d => getDayName(d));`. That will give you an array. Why jump through so many hoops, though, I don't quite understand.

Comment: @ChrisG I have an array literal here but I want to implement it with JSON.

Comment: @jsN00b Yep, I had not known it this before. Thanks! I will try to use this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The JSON text format (which is called that because it looks like JS literals) is completely irrelevant to this question. Instead of passing an array to the Date function (which makes no sense either) you simply iterate over the array and pass each individual date string to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the constructor of Date only takes a string as an argument, so what you actually have to do is to loop over the array of people and for each get the birthday for which then get the day of the week.

Here's my solution:

```
    //get day name from date

const array = [
  {
    name: 'Dwayne Langer',
    birthdate: '06-03-2001'

  },
  {
    name: 'Doffer Henry',
    birthdate: '06-01-2005'
  }
]

const getBirthDate = (person) => person.birthdate;

const getDayName = (dayIndex) =>{
  const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  return days[dayIndex];
}

array.forEach(person => {
    console.log("Day Name", getDayName(new Date(getBirthDate(person)).getDay()));
})
```